# Create an Index of a Large XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, indexing, wikipedia

I have a large bz2 file form wikipedia contain a dump of their articles in xml format.

Getting the text from the dump is not difficult. I am using the following code to parse the xml. I want to know if there is a way to open the orignal bz2 or xml file once its been read, and index it, so that I can associate various lines (e.g., the article for a "Barack Obama") with that index, and then when that line is needed I can go directly to it.

One possibility is splitting the bz2 or xml file into smaller chunks and then indexing those chunks.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to go about finding specific lines as quickly as possible?

```
import bz2
try:
    from lxml import etree
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import re


def _get_namespace(tag):
    namespace = re.match("^{(.*?)}", tag).group(1)
    if not namespace.startswith("http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-"):
        raise ValueError("%s not recognized as MediaWiki database dump"
                         % namespace)
    return namespace

def extract_pages(f):
    elems = (elem for _, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=["end"]))
    elem = next(elems)

    namespace = _get_namespace(elem.tag)
    ns_mapping = {"ns": namespace}
    page_tag = "{%(ns)s}page" % ns_mapping
    text_path = "./{%(ns)s}revision/{%(ns)s}text" % ns_mapping
    id_path = "./{%(ns)s}id" % ns_mapping
    title_path = "./{%(ns)s}title" % ns_mapping
    for elem in elems:
        if elem.tag == page_tag:
            text = elem.find(text_path).text
            if text is None:
                continue
            yield (int(elem.find(id_path).text),
                   elem.find(title_path).text,
                   text)
            elem.clear()
            if hasattr(elem, "getprevious"):
                while elem.getprevious() is not None:
                    del elem.getparent()[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dictionary={}
    f = bz2.BZ2File("simplewiki.xml.bz2", 'rb')

    for pageid, title, text in extract_pages(f):
        print pageid
```

Answer (score 1):

The right tool for doing highly efficient searches through indexed XML is XQuery -- a language for which several high-speed, indexed databases are available. There are Python bindings available, so you can run XQuery query from your Python software, but you'll want to write the actual query itself in XQuery, not Python.

Like SQL databases, XQuery databases have query optimizers, but how you write your query still has a lot to do with how efficiently the indexes are used (and you can control indexing -- vs indexing only id attributes, vs full-text indexes with stemming, and many places between).

If you want an open-source XQuery database with good visualization support to help you with writing and debugging your code, [BaseX](http://basex.org/) may be a good place to begin; it has a great UI, and stays very close to the tip of the language spec, constantly adding new features as they're proposed by the W3C working group controlling XQuery's evolution. [eXist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXist) is another well-maintained open-source XQuery database, whereas [MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/) makes what is probably one of the better-respected commercial XQuery implementations.

See [the list of available clients for BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients), if you want to be able to run your queries from Python.

See also [the detailed documentation on indexes in BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes), to be sure that you write your queries to take advantage of them (and create the indexes you need).

Answer (score 0):

An XML file is not a database... using it as such is inevitably a kind of abuse and trying to add database features like an "index" on top of it will only make things worse IMHO. Besides, contents of a bz2 file are not seekable. If you need a database, import the XML into a database.

For most tasks involving XML dumps, [mediawiki-utilities](http://pythonhosted.org/mediawiki-utilities/core/xml_dump.html) is the fastest option. Just for illustrative purposes, to get the text of [[Barack Obama]] you can do something similar to the example in the documentation, assuming you downloaded the dump of current revisions:

```
from mw.xml_dump import Iterator

# Construct dump file iterator
dump = Iterator.from_file(open("example/dump.xml"))

# Iterate through pages
for page in dump:
    if page.title == "Barack Obama": continue
    # Iterate through a page's revisions
    for revision in page:

        print(revision.text)
```

Comment: Eh? An XQuery database absolutely can/will index an XML file as a database for highly efficient searches.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, interesting, sounds like you should post your suggestion as answer. :)